# Selecting rows where column having number as substring

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to write a query to fetch all the rows with a column containing numbers as substring

```
Data
------
abc123
defgh
wz127bdn
```

Now my desired result is

```
Result
-----
abc123
wz127bdn
```

I wrote the query like

```
SELECT data
FROM table
WHERE data like '%[0-9]%'
```

But this is not fetching the result.

Comment: Maybe you need REGEXP_LIKE instead of LIKE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `REGEXP_LIKE`:

```
SQL> with test(data) as (
  2   select 'abc123' from dual union all
  3   select 'defgh' from dual union all
  4   select 'wz127bdn' from dual  union all
  5   select '[0-9]' from dual
  6  )
  7  select *
  8  from test
  9  where regexp_like(data, '[0-9]')
 10  ;

DATA
--------
abc123
wz127bdn
[0-9]
```

`LIKE` will not interpret '[0-9]' as "look for a digit", but exactly as you write it, thus searching for the string '[0-9]':

```
SQL> with test(data) as (
  2   select 'abc123' from dual union all
  3   select 'defgh' from dual union all
  4   select 'wz127bdn' from dual  union all
  5   select '[0-9]' from dual
  6  )
  7  select *
  8  from test
  9  where data like '%[0-9]%' ;

DATA
--------
[0-9]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `regexp_like()` in Oracle:

```
SELECT data
FROM table
WHERE regexp_like(data, '[0-9]');
```

Note that the wildcards are not necessary, because regular expressions match anywhere in the string.  If you like, you can do:

```
WHERE regexp_like(data, '.*[0-9].*');
```